# How to keep webpage on same place after page refresh on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm wondering how I can keep the website at the same position after a page refresh on my Wordpress website? Every time I do a page refresh the page will always scroll to the top of the page. This is not good for documentation based pages for me since I have to scroll back down to the same position again.

Answer (score 1):

First, assign the `id` to the element you want browser (user) scroll to.

```
<div id="mycomment">
```

Then, generate the url that append with # and id you choose.

Ex.

```
http://example.com/post/1/#mycomment
```